# How to play sound at specific location (horizontal/azimuth) using wav and python ? without libraries

Tags: python, sound, localization

how to set sound location left/right (in mono audio) and azimuth (up/down) of the wave? I know there are a lot of different libraries doing that, but I'm interested in some minimal examples to understand the method.

upd: 
sound is 3d sphere wave, is it possible to somehow define/simulate that using periodic(sin) functions and project wave(sin) on surface (eardrum), for ex new_wave = dot(sin_wave, eardrum_surface) ?

Comment: Is this binaural?  Or stereo speakers?  Or more speakers than two?

Comment: The way to reproduce a (phantom) source somewhere in space is highly dependent on the formulation of the problem and possibly the reproduction setup you use. If you don’t tell us what your setup is and whether you have already some data (such as A- or B-format Ambisonics, raw signals and whether they are mono-, stereo- or “poly-phonic”, etc.) will be very hard to answer and we’d have to speculate. A couple of notes: There is only one way I know of to generate a “true” sound source in space and this is the Wave-Field Synthesis which is practically very hard to realise due to the high (cont.)

Comment: (cont.’ed) hardware complexity. Finally, it’s not entirely clear what you mean by “set the location of a signal in monophonic audio”. Do you mean that the signal you whose position you want to set is monophonic or you want the result to be monophonic, ‘cause the latter is practically not realisable (to my knowledge).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I thought about more general approach, distance and location you can hear even with one ear, probably, something like wave rotation (for ex. project sin wave onto some line or something like that)

Comment: uhm, @tempdeltavalue I am not convinced that you know of what you speak.  Instead of *"something like ... project[ing] a sin[e] wave onto some line"*, I think you need to understand what the state of the art is.  Do you understand [binaural localization](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Arne-Feinkohl/publication/299281975/figure/fig1/AS:669481399513090@1536628212117/Binaural-and-monaural-cues-used-for-sound-localization-a-For-sound-sources-off-the.jpg) and old stuff like how [Blumlein stereo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blumlein_pair) work? Like what an HRTF is?

Comment: I second @robertbristow-johnson on that. You really need to understand how localisation is performed on a cognitive level. The fact that some source is located at some specific azimuthal and elevation angles and distance from you doesn’t mean that it is perceived at this location. V.V.T. has a nice informative answer with some nice resources linked. I suggest you have a look at those (or any other relevant source you may prefer).

Answer (score 3):

Undoubtedly, for a programmatically perceptive person a piece of reliable code is a best instrument to explore the gist of a phenomenon being modeled. Having no readily available code at hand to demonstrate spatial sound-related techniques used in extraction/synthesis/playback applications, I still dare to reference you to Wikipedia articles and Columbia University's course EE E6820: Speech & Audio Processing & Recognition. Even if these references do not suit your purpose, you can use these to specify details and make clear the context of your laconic question.

To write code for spatial sound-related applications, a programmer needs to know about [the biological process of sound localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization). To verify that you are familiar with the material of this article, test your knowledge of

- the 'cone of confusion'
- the precedence effect
- Interaural Time Difference (ITD) and Interaural Intensity Difference (IID)
- the Head-Related Transfer Function (HRTF) and the Head-Related Impulse
  Response (HRIR)
- pinna-related frequency response of the auditory system for vertical sound localization

The knowledge of general signal processing-related principles of acoustic location (not covered in the Wiki article) is a must-have. The knowledge of sound processing-related aspects for the human auditory system, covered in the Wiki article section 'Signal Processing', is highly desirable.

The [**Lecture 8: Spatial sound**](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/%7Edpwe/e6820/lectures/L08-spatial.pdf) course notes of Columbia University's course EE E6820  adds formulas, block diagrams and flowcharts, and enriches the Wiki article content with instructive visuals.

As one masters the spatial sound theory presented in these two documents, one can write the code like that which you request in your question. And even the highest quality demo code (if this exists) is next to useless for the person without the background discussed in these references. Of course, the demo code is a great thing to start development, even for the person with the necessary theoretical background.

Comment: The link to “Lecture 8” you provide is dead. I get a “Page not found” from the Columbia University website.

Comment: Try https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/e6820/lectures/L08-spatial.pdf

Comment: Yep this works. I think you should update your answer with it.

Comment: @V.V.T thank you for materials, but I meant something more general, for example project sin wave on some line and in this way simulate angle at least in 2d ..

Comment: @ZaellixA It seems to be a bug in the SE.SP site. The `~` character gets changed to `%7E` when the link is in-lined.

Comment: Yes, replacing char '~' with a char sequence "%7E" can be counted as a bug, although the site engine only performs standard-prescribed URI normalization (percent-encoding of data octets within the resource string). But RFC 3986, section 2.3 Unreserved Characters (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) prescribes exemption rules: "For consistency, percent-encoded octets in the ranges of ALPHA, DIGIT, hyphen, period, underscore, or tilde (%7E) should not be created by URI producers and, when found in a URI, should be decoded to their corresponding unreserved characters by URI normalizers."

Comment: SE's site engine is an URI producer and should not create a percent-encoded octet for the tilde char. Still, violation of this rule could be corrected by URI normalizers of your browser or Columbia Uni's web server, but these also seem to ignore Section 2.3 Unreserved Characters' stipulation. Pay attention that the site engine performs URI normalization only when URI is entered via a hyperlink control; it does not perform URI normalization for a typed URI resource, as in my comment above. Summing up, @PeterK: (concerning a hyperlink edit) Nice try, but to no avail.

Comment: Not being aware of the means to communicate this info to the site maintainers, I'm writing this in the comment section of the post where the problem is revealed.

Comment: @V.V.T The usual way to report bugs is to write a post on Meta with the `bug` tag. I've done that [here](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1811/80) for this issue.